# How to change number of column in a row on resize - Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need some help to change number of columns in a row dynanamically when resizing window. For example, for large and medium screen, there should be 3 columns in a row, for small there should be 2 and for extra small only 1 column

Something like this

For large and medium

**{col-1}{col-2}{col-3}**

**{col-4}{col-5}{col-6}**

For small

**{col-1}{col-2}**

**{col-3}{col-4}**

**{col-5}{col-6}**

and similar for extra small

What I have done now is made a row and put 3 columns in it

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Some content here for column 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Some content here for column 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Some content here for column 3
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Some content here for column 4
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Some content here for column 5
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Some content here for column 6
    </div>
</div>
```

but using this trick, on small screen it show 2 column in a row, and in next row just 1 column

**{col-1}{col-2}**

**{col-3}**

**{col-4}{col-5}**

**{col-6}**

Can anybody please help me to get this fixed.

Thanks

Comment: thanks for responding, added my code in edited version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good example of when to use Bootstrap's [column wrapping](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping).

Put all of the columns in 1 `.row`...

http://www.codeply.com/go/zyTOcNXo0m

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Some content here for column 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Some content here for column 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Some content here for column 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Some content here for column 4
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Some content here for column 5
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Some content here for column 6
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/zyTOcNXo0m

Comment: thanks this works :) I didn't knew that we can add more than 12 columns in a row. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Responsive Grid view for bootstrap

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
      </div>
 </div>
```