# bootstrap column order and wrapping

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have four columns that I would like to display as two rows (of two) on medium devices and four rows on small devices. The problem being that the content needs to be in order vertically, so that the columns on medium devices are arranged like this:

> ```
> ONE  THREE
> TWO  FOUR
> ```

and on small devices like this:

> ```
> ONE
> TWO
> THREE
> FOUR
> ```

I have been unable to accomplish the desired layout using the col-sm-push-* class or any other tricks I've tried from my research. It seems to me that it should be a simple thing to do, but I'm baffled.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">ONE</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">TWO</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">THREE</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">FOUR</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change number of column in a row on resize - Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438312/how-to-change-number-of-column-in-a-row-on-resize-bootstrap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to nest the DIVs like this..

http://www.codeply.com/go/G7D6WvVIqZ

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="col-sm-12">ONE</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">TWO</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="col-sm-12">THREE</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">FOUR</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I also set the padding to 0 on the col-sm-6 divs in order to space everything uniformly.

Answer (score 2):

Use nesting to group your `<div>`'s.

Here's an example: 
https://jsbin.com/yawoka/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-6">ONE</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">TWO</div>
      </div>  
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-6">THREE</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">FOUR</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `insertBefore` function of jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).resize(function(){

      if($(this).width()>992 && $(this).width()<1199)
    {
          $('.three').insertBefore('.two');   
        }else{
                $('.two').insertBefore('.three');  
    }
    })

})
```

Here's the working link:http://jsfiddle.net/wVVbT/171/