# Bootstrap How to clear bootstrap columns last child

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="testcontainer red  col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">box 1</div>
        <div class="testcontainer green col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">box 2</div>
        <div class="testcontainer blue col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">box 3</div>
        <div class="testcontainer purple col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">box 4</div>

    </div>

  <div class="row">
        <div class="testcontainer red  col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">box 5</div>
        <div class="testcontainer green col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">box 6</div>
        <div class="testcontainer blue col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">box 7</div>
        <div class="testcontainer purple col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">box 8</div>

    </div>
```

When is display in tablet 3 column how to clear the last child to remove right space?
[view for tablet column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4Q02.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Put all of the columns in a single row...

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="testcontainer red  col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">box 1</div>
        <div class="testcontainer green col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">box 2</div>
        <div class="testcontainer blue col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">box 3</div>
        <div class="testcontainer purple col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">box 4</div>
        <div class="testcontainer red  col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">box 5</div>
        <div class="testcontainer green col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">box 6</div>
        <div class="testcontainer blue col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">box 7</div>
        <div class="testcontainer purple col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">box 8</div>
</div>
```

Similar question: [How to change number of column in a row on resize - Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438312/how-to-change-number-of-column-in-a-row-on-resize-bootstrap/43438549)

Comment: I need to make it for loop  (sorry for my english)

Comment: I don't understand. You just need to repeat the columns in the same `row`

Comment: sorry I'm not good in english it's hard to explain ,  I make my website with php site  and the second row is the loop content

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Don't loop the row, only loop the columns.